# How to use imperative apex from Salesforce Sites?

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I am surfacing a LWC on Salesforce Sites however, I am not able to implement imperative apex from a button click.

When I add the same LWC to a record page in Salesforce and click the button, then the imperative call does work.

It's not clear from the docs if one can implement imperative apex from Salesforce Sites? Or do I need to do this via lightning message service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can call Apex from sites/digital experiences. The key is permissions. Make sure the Guest User has access to the Apex class for unauthenticated sites, and that the member profiles have access to the Apex class for authenticated site users.